# Dying Hyper-V Guests

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

We've run into a problem twice now with WS2008 guests running under Hyper-V where the guest machine seems to basically die after a reboot.  The guest image does boot up, but never comes on the network and if I log into the console from the Hyper-V management tool I am not able run any apps.  I can log into the machine, but if I try to run the event log viewer or any other admin tool the app simply never launches.

In the latest example, we have a gues running CRM - I applied a CRM update that required a rebot.  The guest never came back on the network, so I logged into the host and see the guest running.  I can log into the guest from the Hyper-V console, but shortly after logging the explorer shell becomes unresponsive.  If I try launching Event Viewer while the shee is active it simply never starts.

This is the exact same behavior I saw in another machine a few weeks back.

Couple of notes:
-The host is a WS2008 Std Ed machine 64 Bit
-The guest images were both WS2008 Std Ed 64 bit machines also
-There are no meaningful entries in the event log on the host
-I have tried rebooting the host - no change in behavior

Comment: (Just making a suggestion) Next time you apply a similar update to a guest VM, take a snapshot of it before you run it. That way if it goes belly up like this, you can just rollback to the snapshot. If this fixes the issue then it was the update that caused the problem. Backing up your VMs is a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe there is a deeper issue (hard drive maybe?). I would reboot the server (after backing up) and run PC-check burn in for a few hours to see if anything pops up.

We had an issue with one VM acting strangely (the network became nonresponsive) and it ended up being a corrupt vhd.